# SpriteKit: create touchable zones inside a big sprite - to handle SKActions based on where was touched inside the sprite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Imagine we have a character which should respond to touches. So based on where it was touched (on the head, on the hands) I run specific actions for animations.

*The question is: **how to detect (depict) those touchable zones?***

*Here is basic code:*

```
@interface MyScene ()
  @property (nonatomic) SKSpriteNode * character;
@end

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
 if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

  _character = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"character_001.png"];
  CGPoint position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
  [self addChild:_character];

 }
 return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

 UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:_character];
 CGSize charSize = _character.size;
 NSLog(@"characterSize width: %f and characterSize height: %f",  charSize.width,charSize.height);
}
```

Strategies I'm trying to implement:

If I create UIViews rectangles above the character, and make them transparent (in View Controller) is it correct way?
 - Create SKNodes and place them above the character in this SKScene.

**How would you implement those touchable zones - iOS/Game developers ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can add child SKNodes to your character node, and then respond to touches on those.

```
SKSpriteNode *childNode = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
[_character addChild: childNode];
```